# sequences in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, sequence

my xml input is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<foo>  <bar>bar</bar> 
       <bar>bar</bar> 
       <foobar>foobar</foobar> 
       <foobar>foobar</foobar> 
       <foobar>foobar</foobar>
       <bar>bar</bar>
       <bar>bar</bar> 
</foo>
```

Output using xslt  should be

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <foo>  
 <s> 
 <s> 
 <bar>bar</bar>  
 <bar>bar</bar>
 </s>
 <s> 
 <foobar>foobar></foobar>
 <foobar>foobar></foobar>
 <foobar>foobar></foobar>
 </s> 
 <s>      
 <bar>bar</bar>  
 <bar>bar</bar> 
 </s>
 </s>
</foo>
```

the output should  to have sequence-of elements inside a parent. Mixed sequence-of elements will be moved inside parents node “s”. Is there any xslt command that detects the sequence and process the xml accordingly.Many thanks.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? It's pretty trivial in 2 with `for-each-group` but much trickier in 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21792830/3016153), use the id of the first preceding sibling whose name is different in order to group the records:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="adjacentByName" match="foo/*" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<foo><s>
    <xsl:for-each select="foo/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('adjacentByName', generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1]))[1])]">
        <s>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('adjacentByName', generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(name()=name(current()))][1]))">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </s>
    </xsl:for-each>
</s></foo>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

> But the output i am getting is not same as my desired output...

When applied to your (cleaned up) input of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<foo>
    <bar>bar</bar> 
    <bar>bar</bar> 
    <foobar>foobar</foobar> 
    <foobar>foobar</foobar> 
    <foobar>foobar</foobar>
    <bar>bar</bar>
    <bar>bar</bar> 
</foo>
```

the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
  <s>
    <s>
      <bar>bar</bar>
      <bar>bar</bar>
    </s>
    <s>
      <foobar>foobar</foobar>
      <foobar>foobar</foobar>
      <foobar>foobar</foobar>
    </s>
    <s>
      <bar>bar</bar>
      <bar>bar</bar>
    </s>
  </s>
</foo>
```

which to me seems to be exactly the result you have asked for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <foo>  
 <s> 
 <s> 
 <bar>bar</bar>  
 <bar>bar</bar>
 </s>
 <s> 
 <foobar>foobar></foobar>
 <foobar>foobar></foobar>
 <foobar>foobar></foobar>
 </s> 
 <s>      
 <bar>bar</bar>  
 <bar>bar</bar> 
 </s>
 </s>
</foo>
```

except for the `>` characters inside the `<foobar>` elements, which I have removed from the input.

--

### P.S. Please DO NOT delete your question after it has been answered.

Comment: Well, it *is* somewhat "advanced". You need to be familiar with [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) before you can tackle this.

Comment: its putting each elements in every "s" not the group of same elements like
    <foo>  
    <s> 
    <s> 
    <bar>bar</bar> 
    </s>
    <s> 
    <bar>bar</bar>
    </s>
    .....
    </s>

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion. But i am using xsltproc and the output i am getting is this.                                                          `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <foo>
 <s>
 <s>
 <bar>bar</bar>
 </s>
 <s>
 <bar>bar</bar>
 </s>
 <s>
 <foobar>foobar&gt;</foobar>
 </s>
 <s>
 <foobar>foobar&gt;</foobar>
 </s>
 <s>
 <foobar>foobar&gt;</foobar>
 </s>
 <s>
 <bar>bar</bar>
 </s>
 <s>
 <bar>bar</bar>
 </s>
 </s>
</foo>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help you with that. I have tested the above code in Xalan, Saxon **and** libxslt - which is what xsltproc uses, I believe.

Comment: Thanx again for ur feedback....i used that link to test it (http://www.xsltcake.com/) when i used .NET xslt processor its giving right desired output...but if i use javascript xslt processor its giving different output......the same i am getting with my xsltproc..

Comment: I am getting the correct output on that site with **both** processors: http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/kE1ZnI If you see something different, then the problem is likely something in your system that affects both the xsltproc and your browser processors.

Comment: @michael....just to test i added a child element (bar2) to foobar element. but in output bar2 is sequenced with the bar elements as well as foobar..why is that?..thnks in advance..u can c it here..http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/r6qkno/3

Comment: @Sam This is what I get:http://i.stack.imgur.com/knfnE.png If this is not the correct result, then I don't understand the question. Perhaps you need to post a new one, with a more representative input example.