# XSLT: Process all following-sibling until a certain condition is met without processed nodes getting re-processed

Tags: xml, xslt

Consider the following XML structure:

```
<a>
    <t>abc</t>
</a>
<a type="start"></a>
<b>
    <t>ignore</t>
</b>
<a></a>    
<a>
    <t>1</t>
</a>
<a>
    <t>2</t>
</a>
<a>
    <t>3</t>
</a>
<b>
    <t>ignore</t>
</b>
<a>
    <t>4</t>
</a>
<a type="end"></a>
<a>
    <t>def</t>
</a>
```

I need to get the sum of contents of all the `a` tags between the `a` tags with attribute value `start` and `end`.

I attempted it with the following XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@type='start'">
            <merged>
                <xsl:call-template name="getMergedText">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="''"/>
                <xsl:call-template>
            </merged>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <single>
                <xsl:value-of select="t"/>
            </single>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="getMergedText">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::a[1]/@type='end'">
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::a[1]/t">
            <xsl:variable name="text.update">
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::a[1]/t"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::a[1]">
                <xsl:call-template name="getMergedText">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text.update"/>
                <xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::a[1]">
                <xsl:call-template name="getMergedText">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
                <xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The required output is:

```
<single>abc</single>
<merged>1234</merged>
<single>def</single>
```

The output I am getting is:

```
<single>abc</single>
<merged>1234</merged>
<single>1</single>
<single>2</single>
<single>3</single>
<single>4</single>
<single>def</single>
```

How can I avoid the reprocessing of the `a` nodes already processed by `getMergedText` template?

Thnx in advance!!

**Note:** I am working with XSLT 1.0. There can be multiple instances of the start-end node pairs in the XML with any number of nodes before, after and in between the pairs.

Comment: xslt 1 or 2? Have you checked if Muenchian Grouping solves the problem for you?

Comment: xslt 1.0. I have never heard of "Muenchian Grouping", will read it now..

Comment: **1.** Your XML source is missing a root element (and so does your output). **2.** Will there be only one sequence of start...end in the entire source document? And only one element before and after the sequence?

Comment: The missing root items are in the sample xml only. My real xml, xsl and output does has the root nodes. No there can be multiple instances of start-end pairs and there can be any number of nodes before, after and in between the pairs.

Comment: Have a look at a quite similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889151/xml-sequence-using-xslt/21889633#21889633

Comment: @michael.hor257k went completely over my head. I guess I would have to read Muenchian Grouping after all, if there is no simpler solution....

Comment: I don't think this is simple at all (in XSLT 1.0). And yes, Muenchian grouping is "required reading" here.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient approach here may be something that I've heard described as "sibling recursion", using tail-recursive templates to simulate a "while loop" type of structure.  The top template starts by processing just the *first* `a` element, and then the last thing each template does is apply the appropriate template to the *next* `a` element.

```
<xsl:template match="---whatever matches the parent element of the a's---">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="a[1]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[@type = 'start']">
  <!-- edge case - start followed immediately by end shouldn't generate
       a "merged" element -->
  <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::a[1][@type = 'end'])">
    <merged>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="merge" select="following-sibling::a[1]" />
    </merged>
  </xsl:if>
  <!-- continue with the a after the "end" -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="
      following-sibling::a[@type = 'end'][1]/following-sibling::a[1]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
  <single><xsl:value-of select="t"/></single>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::a[1]" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- stop the merge when we get the the "end" -->
<xsl:template match="a[@type = 'end']" mode="merge" />

<xsl:template match="a" mode="merge">
  <xsl:value-of select="t" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::a[1]" mode="merge" />
</xsl:template>
```

Note the difference between `following-sibling::a[1][@type = 'end']` (check whether the immediately following `a` element is one that has `type="end"`) and `following-sibling::a[@type = 'end'][1]` (find the nearest following `a` which does have `type="end"`).

Answer (score 1):

On second thought, maybe this *could* be done in a somewhat simpler manner:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='xml' version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' indent='yes'/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="a[count(preceding-sibling::a[@type='start'])=count(preceding-sibling::a[@type='end'])]"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[not(@type='start')]">
    <single><xsl:value-of select="t" /></single>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[@type='start']">
<xsl:variable name="prevStarts" select="count(preceding-sibling::a[@type='start'])" />
    <group>
        <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="following-sibling::a[count(preceding-sibling::a[@type='end'])=$prevStarts]"
        mode="merge"/>
    </group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a" mode="merge">
    <xsl:value-of select="t" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to a modified input in the form of:

```
<root>
    <a><t>abc</t></a>

    <a type="start"/>
    <b><t>ignore</t>
    </b>
    <a/>
    <a><t>1</t></a>
    <a><t>2</t></a>
    <a><t>3</t></a>
    <b><t>ignore</t></b>
    <a><t>4</t></a>
    <a type="end"/>

    <a><t>def</t></a>
    <a><t>ghi</t></a>

    <a type="start"/>
    <b><t>ignore</t>
    </b>
    <a/>
    <a><t>5</t></a>
    <a><t>6</t></a>
    <a><t>7</t></a>
    <b><t>ignore</t></b>
    <a><t>8</t></a>
    <a type="end"/>

    <a><t>jkl</t></a>
</root>
```

the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output>
  <single>abc</single>
  <group>1234</group>
  <single>def</single>
  <single>ghi</single>
  <group>5678</group>
  <single>jkl</single>
</output>
```