# Transform xml using xsl with different datatypes into different html-tables

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

Need to transform different Items into different tables. Each time the item-type changes, a new table should be started (With some comment above and different table heading). The sorting order (seqnr) needs to be kept.

Came up with a Solution which puts everything in one table and emits a new  tableheader, if type changes. But what I really want to do is to close the preceding table, emit some bla-bla, and start a new one. All my attempts resulted in xsl-errors, because needed/wanted to emit unmatched tags (That is: when type-change detected, emit `</table>, some text, <table><th><tr>...</th>`).

So as I understand, this results from 'beginner thinking in a procedural language', but still can't find the trick.

(This example works ok with Firefox 51.0.1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#stylesheet"?>
<doc>
<xsl:stylesheet id="stylesheet" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet"/>
<xsl:variable name="PersonHeader">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>seqnr</th>
    <th>weight</th>
  </tr>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="FruitHeader">
  <tr>
    <th>Fruit</th>
    <th>seqnr</th>
    <th>color</th>
    <th>size</th>
  </tr>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="Data">
  <html>
    <body>
      <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="Item">
          <xsl:sort select="seqnr" data-type="number"/>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="type = 'Person'">
              <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::Item[1]/type = type)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$PersonHeader"/>
              </xsl:if>
              <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="seqnr"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="weight"/></td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="type = 'Fruit'">
              <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::Item[1]/type = type)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$FruitHeader"/>
              </xsl:if>
              <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="seqnr"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="color"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="size"/></td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
<Data>
    <Item>
      <seqnr>1000</seqnr>
      <type>Fruit</type>
      <name>Banana</name>
      <color>yellow</color>
      <size>200</size>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <seqnr>101</seqnr>
      <type>Person</type>
      <name>Hugo</name>
      <weight>70</weight>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <seqnr>102</seqnr>
      <type>Person</type>
      <name>Bert</name>
      <weight>81</weight>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <seqnr>103</seqnr>
      <type>Fruit</type>
      <name>Orange</name>
      <color>orange</color>
      <size>150</size>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <seqnr>104</seqnr>
      <type>Fruit</type>
      <name>Apple</name>
      <color>red</color>
      <size>100</size>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <seqnr>105</seqnr>
      <type>Person</type>
      <name>Charly</name>
      <weight>76</weight>
    </Item>
  </Data> 
</doc>
```

Comment: I don't think it is a problem with procedural programming applied in a declarative language, you first have to understand that XSLT is XML and have to learn the XML syntax rules respectively use an editor or an IDE that supports you in creating well-formed XML/XSLT. As for the problem of creating a table for each `type` of `Items`, that is a grouping problem to be solved in XSLT 1.0 using Muenchian grouping as shown in http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html or in hundreds of examples of answers to previous questions.

Comment: Hmm, thats right. But I dont want to group them by type, they have to occur on the order dictated by seqnr.

Comment: See if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21889633/3016153