# XSLT 1.0 grouping for text output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

For a project with soil data im trying to group by STRAT whenever the data changes with increasing depth.

Thanks to a lot of help already I am getting already onthat platform there are already some good results, but its not perfect still.

Example:

XML:

```
<LAYERS> 
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="1.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geological_formation_1" />
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="94.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geological_formation_1" />
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="94.20" INTV="2" INDEX_ZONE="-1" EGART="Lost_Data"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="95.00" PETRO="Gravel" STRAT="geological_formation_1" />
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="100.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geological_formation_2" />
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="100.50" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geological_formation_4" />
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="101.50" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geological_formation_4" />
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="101.80" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geological_formation_5" />
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="102.90" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geological_formation_3" />
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="103.00" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geological_formation_3" />
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="103.25" INTV="2" INDEX_ZONE="-1" EGART="Lost_Data"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="103.69" PETRO="Sand" STRAT="geological_formation_2"/>
    <LAYER DEPTHTO="104.00" PETRO="Mud" STRAT="geological_formation_2" />
</LAYERS>
```

using with xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="layer-by-strat" match="LAYER" use="@STRAT" />

<xsl:template match="LAYERS" >
    <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
        <xsl:with-param name="layers" select="LAYER[not(@EGART='Lost_Data')][count(. | key('layer-by-strat', @STRAT)[1]) = 1]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-rows">
    <xsl:param name="layers" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:param name="accumulated-depth" select="'0.00'"/>
    <xsl:if test="$layers">
        <xsl:variable name="strat" select="$layers[1]/@STRAT" />
        <xsl:variable name="max-depth" select="key('layer-by-strat', $strat)[last()]/@DEPTHTO" />
        <!-- output -->
        <xsl:text>ZONE "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$strat" />
        <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$accumulated-depth" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$max-depth" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="layers" select="$layers[position() > 1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="accumulated-depth" select="$max-depth"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is:

```
ZONE "geological_formation_1" 0.00 95.00
ZONE "geological_formation_2" 95.00 104.00
ZONE "geological_formation_4" 104.00 101.50
ZONE "geological_formation_5" 101.50 101.80
ZONE "geological_formation_3" 101.80 103.00
```

BUT i need an output like that:

```
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_1" 0.00 95.00
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_2" 95.00 100.00
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_4" 100.00 101.50
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_5" 101.50 101.80
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_3" 101.80 103.00
ZONE "geologiscal_formation_2" 103.25 104.00
```

The tricky parts are that "Lost_Data" is common and need to be ignored in the grouping process.

If there are any ideas how to accomplish/improve the stylesheet or maybe using a new way to get the desired output, id be very thankful.

Kind regards

UPDATE:
I was tinkering around and got the the point where it almost works, but i cannot ignore LAYER with `EGART="Lost_Data"`. ALso the first group needs a 0.00 as the first number

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="adj" match="LAYER" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::LAYER[not(@STRAT = current()/@STRAT)][1])" />

    <xsl:template name="GOCAD" match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="ZONES"/>
    </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="ZONES" match="/*" mode="ZONES">
   <xsl:for-each select="LAYER[generate-id() = generate-id(key('adj', generate-id(preceding-sibling::LAYER[not(@STRAT = current()/@STRAT)][1]))[1])]">
      <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('adj', generate-id(preceding-sibling::LAYER[not(@STRAT = current()/@STRAT)][1]))" />
      <xsl:variable name="precedingZONE" select="preceding-sibling::LAYER[1]"/>
      <xsl:variable name="DEPTHFROM" select="$precedingZONE/@DEPTHTO"/>
      
      <xsl:text>ZONE "</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@STRAT"/>
      <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="$current-group">
        <xsl:sort select="$DEPTHFROM" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1 ">
          <xsl:value-of select="$DEPTHFROM"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="$current-group">
        <xsl:sort select="@DEPTHTO" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1 ">
          <xsl:value-of select="@DEPTHTO"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text> -1</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
ZONE "geological_formation_1"  94.00 -1
ZONE "" 94.00 94.20 -1
ZONE "geological_formation_1" 94.20 95.00 -1
ZONE "geological_formation_2" 95.00 100.00 -1
ZONE "geological_formation_4" 100.00 101.50 -1
ZONE "geological_formation_5" 101.50 101.80 -1
ZONE "geological_formation_3" 101.80 103.00 -1
ZONE "" 103.00 103.25 -1
ZONE "geological_formation_2" 103.25 104.00 -1
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly the logic you want to implement here.

Comment: Basicly the idea is to avoid multiple repeatings of the ZONE with the same STRAT due to LAYER with same STRAT. With each next layer the STRAT can be the same as the layer above, but it must not. In case its the same, those two layers shoud be grouped into one ZONE. That goes on until the STRAT changes and is different to the above layer.
But STRAT can be the same later on, like "geologiscal_formation_2" at the very bottom.

Right now i get the result: " ZONE "geologiscal_formation_2" 94.00 104.00 " where the 104 is the very last DEPTH. 




I hope its clearer now?

Comment: I am afraid not. The layers grouped by STRAT do not have a ZONE.

Comment: Sry, ill try it differently:
Every node LAYER contains a STRAT. What im trying to get is a textoutput-group called ZONE which picks the first LAYER, watches the STRAT and goes on to the next LAYER. IF the STRAT in the next LAYER is the same, it goes on to the third LAYER and chcecks the STRAT. The very moment the STRAT is different a new group ZONE (next line in text-output) will be created with the different STRAT.

All regarding the depths and Lost_Data.

The enddepth is given directly by DEPTHTO, the beginning depths is being created by the LAYER above.

Comment: So basically you want the equivalent of XSLT 2.0 `group-adjacent`?

Comment: Yes, the group-adjacent would be pure gold, but i cannot use that in 1.0 as far i know :/

i edited my post a little bit, maybe it helps

Comment: Implementing `group-adjacent` in XSLT 1.0 is possible, but not trivial You can see an example of one method here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21889633/3016153 . In your case it's even more complex because of the need to "carry" the last depth to the next group.

Comment: Thansk, i thinks its similar to what ive got in the update at the end of the question. Im losing hope in realising that with xslt1.0 :/

Comment: I am sure it's possible (after all, XSLT 1.0 is Turing-complete), but it would require more time than I can afford to spend here.

Comment: I understand and i am still very thankful for your help all time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going.  It doesn't account for EGART="Lost_Data" being in the first position.  But, you should be able to make that adjustment if you need to.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="allLayers">
    <xsl:for-each select="//LAYER">
      <xsl:variable name="STRAT" select="@STRAT"/>
      
      <xsl:element name="element">
        <xsl:element name="first">
          <xsl:if test="boolean(@STRAT) and not(preceding-sibling::LAYER[boolean(@STRAT)][1]/@STRAT = $STRAT)">
            <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="STRAT">
          <xsl:value-of select="@STRAT"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>
        </xsl:element>      
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- msxml is a namespace.  You will have to use you own namespace. -->
  <xsl:variable name="allLayersList" select="msxml:node-set($allLayers)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="layers">
    <xsl:for-each select="//LAYER">
      <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id(.)"/>
    
      <xsl:variable name="STRAT">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="boolean(@STRAT)">
            <xsl:value-of select="@STRAT"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::LAYER[boolean(@STRAT)][1]/@STRAT"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
    
      <xsl:element name="element">
        <xsl:element name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="group">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$allLayersList/element[id = $id and first = 'true']">
              <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="$allLayersList/element[id = $id]/preceding-sibling::element[first = 'true'][1]/id"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="STRAT">
            <xsl:value-of select="$STRAT"/>
          </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="DEPTHTO">
          <xsl:value-of select="@DEPTHTO"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- msxml is a namespace.  You will have to use you own namespace. -->
  <xsl:variable name="layerList" select="msxml:node-set($layers)"/>

  <xsl:template match="LAYER">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id(.)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="group" select="$layerList/element[id = $id]/group"/>
    <xsl:variable name="strat" select="$layerList/element[id = $id]/STRAT"/>
    <!-- Is this the first in the group.  -->
    <xsl:if test="$allLayersList/element[id = $id and first = 'true']">
     <xsl:variable name="accumulated-depth">
        <xsl:choose>
          <!-- Is there a preceding group -->
          <xsl:when test="$layerList/element[group = $group][1]/preceding-sibling::element[1]">
            <xsl:variable name="precedingGroup" select="$layerList/element[group = $group][1]/preceding-sibling::element[1]/group"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$layerList/element[group = $precedingGroup]">
              <xsl:sort select="DEPTHTO" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
              <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="DEPTHTO"/>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'0.00'"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
    
      <xsl:variable name="max-depth">
        <xsl:for-each select="$layerList/element[group = $group]">
          <xsl:sort select="DEPTHTO" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="DEPTHTO"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
    
      <xsl:text>ZONE "</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$strat" />
      <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$accumulated-depth" />
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$max-depth" />
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the reply, it seems really like you have been putting a lot of thought into it! The topic "Namespace" is actually new to me. After some quick research, it appears to be used to differentiate node having the same names. That is why i dont understand where and why ,and how, i need to implement namespaces. Is there any chance you could help me here more?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio.  And my namespace is declared as  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"      You can see that msxml is the prefix I use in my code....  You may be using something other than Microsoft: Saxon, Altova, ect...   Figure out what your namespace should be and add it.  And make sure you change the msxml prefix I used to the same prefix as your namespace.  If you are not using XSLT 1.0 you don't even need to use the node-set function.  You can rename to variable before it to the same as the node-set variable, remove it, and you are good.

Comment: I just updated the code.  I added the namespace to the stylesheet tag.  But, this works for Microsoft.  You have to make it work for what you are using.

Comment: Jey John, im running on msxml 6 and using the microsoft windows build in engine. thats why im "stuck" with xslt 1.0 :)

Your answer was great, it worked the way i imagined.

I see your last step using "node()|@*".

Since the LAYERS node is integreated nex tto many other nodes, i will need to next it somehow inside the whole stylsheet. Maybe it iwll be a new question, i will need to try out first.

Comment: I was able to implement your answer to my whole stylsheet. Great help of you, thank you. Reading the workflow is interesting to me and i learned a lot again.